# Javascript time if statement 8.30am

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript function called showbanner() which is designed to change the src of an image based on our opening hours. It's worked well for ages...

```
function showbanner() { 
    now = new Date();
    t = now.getUTCHours();
    m = now.getUTCMinutes();
    if (t>9 && t<17) document.getElementById('theImg').src="/Img/Open.png"; 
    else document.getElementById('theImg').src="/Img/Closed.png";
}
```

However, we've just changed our opening hours from **9am - 5pm** to **8.30am - 5pm** and I can't for the life of me work out how to express 8.30am in the above if statement!

Could I do:

```
 if ((t>8 && t<9 && m>30) && t<17)....
```

?????

Thanks in advance for any help!

Cheers,
Matt

Comment: `t > 8 && t < 9` is false for all `t`.

Comment: Don't forget to declare all your local variables with `var` **!!!**

Comment: @delan Only for integral t. If t is simply a real number then any value in the open-range (8, 9) matches. Imagine where t represents "fractional hours". (It doesn't in the posted code, but I'm being pedantic about the comment ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make a variable which stores the time in military time format.

```
function showbanner() { 
    var now = new Date();
    var t = now.getUTCHours();
    var m = now.getUTCMinutes();
    var mil = 100*t+m; // Military time
    if (mil >= 830 && mil <= 1700) { // Between 8:30 AM and 5:00 PM
        document.getElementById('theImg').src="/Img/Open.png"; 
    } else {
        document.getElementById('theImg').src="/Img/Closed.png";
    }
}
```

That could make it easier to make future changes.

Comment: +1 Because ... of all the answers as of yet, **it actually simplifies the problem**. However, I would move t/v/mil generation to another function, say, `getUTCInMilitary` or whatnot. This eliminates the need for the first comment entirely ;-)

Comment: Thank you. As you say, this has really simplified the problem.

Comment: A related approach would be to make hours fraction, e.g.: `h >= 8.5`

Comment: @pst, I wasn't sure if that would work? Doesn't getUTCHours() only return the whole hour?

Comment: @Matt: The approach he meant was something along the lines of: `var h = t + m/60.0`;

Answer (score 2):

```
function showbanner() { 
    var now = new Date();
    var t = now.getUTCHours();
    var m = now.getUTCMinutes();
    if ((t > 8 || t === 8 && m <= 30) && t < 17) document.getElementById('theImg').src="/Img/Open.png"; 
    else document.getElementById('theImg').src="/Img/Closed.png";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this(convert 8:30 to seconds which is 510 and check if (t*60)+m is greater than that):

```
function showbanner() { 
    now = new Date();
    t = now.getUTCHours();
    m = now.getUTCMinutes();
    if (((t*60) + m) >510 && t<17) 
        document.getElementById('theImg').src="/Img/Open.png"; 
    else
        document.getElementById('theImg').src="/Img/Closed.png";
}
```

Comment: -1 for very unreadable magic number 510, with no comment describing it in the code.

Comment: @Sebastian: I think you missed the first line of my post which says converting 8:30 to seconds is 510.

Comment: @Cybernate: I modified my comment. Most likely, the accepted answer will by copied directly into the site; and with the code part copied as is, it'd be pretty unreadable.

Comment: @Sebastian: I am not sure if the answers provided in SO are for a direct copy paste or to give an idea to resolve the problem OP.

Comment: @Cybernate: Perhaps not, but my -1 stands with the code as is.

Comment: @Sebastian: I am not at all concerned about the -1. I just wanted to mention that the description was indeed given in the post.